# Self-made Distance Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I want to create a distance matrix based on two columns which represent Point IDs and a column representing my "distance". The distances are actually normalized maximum slope values, so basically i want a distance matrix on the maximum slope between two points. I have one row for every connection which looks somehow like this:

```
Origin = c(10001,10001,10002,10002,20001,20001)
Destin = c(10002,20001,10001,20001,10001,10002)
```

and a third vector with the maximum slope values:

```
maxSlope = c(0.47, 0.12, 0.47, 0.32,0.12,0.32)
```

Now i would like to have a table which looks like this:

```
NaN   10001 10002 20001
10001 NaN   0.47  0.12
10002 0.47  NaN   0.32
20001 0.12  0.32  NaN
```

I actually don't care what values are in the place of "NaN".

I'm pretty new to R. Does anybody have a good solution for doing this?
Regards, 
simoet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(maxSlope~Origin+Destin)
       Destin
Origin  10001 10002 20001
  10001  0.00  0.47  0.12
  10002  0.47  0.00  0.32
  20001  0.12  0.32  0.00
```

Comment: However, it inserts values that did not exist before. In the example this would result in adding values like 10003, 10004,...,10010,20000 and then continuing with 20001. The distance at these values is always zero. 
Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: It sounds like those variables are `factor`s. Either use `as.character` on them or re-factor them.